# PHP push value into sub array of key

Tags: php, push, associative-array

I have an array of meta that I'm saving for a user that looks like so

```
$testArray = array("67" => array("400", "402", "1488"), "84" => array("599", 620"), "92" => array("740")
```

If no array for user exists, I need to build it given a key and value

```
$testArray = ["67" => ["400"]]
```

If $testArray is not empty, I need to use the key I know to find the corresponding array and add the the value given

```
$testArray["67"][] = "1500"
```

So the output should be

```
array("67" => array("400", "1500"))
```

This method adds nothing to an array that exists and every combination I've tried either adds nothing or a nested array

Comment: *This however creates nested arrays after two executions instead* do you have this in a loop? Can you expand the code to how it looks? Or how do you add more values there? Where do the other values come from?

Comment: Are you referring to two different pieces of data as `$testArray`? I find your question Unclear.  What is the existing/parent array called and what is the new value/variable called?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking out for something like following:

```
$key = "red";
$valOne = "blue";
$valTwo = "green";
$alpha = get_data_array();
if(count($alpha))
{
   $finalArr = [$key => [$valOne,$valTwo]];
}
```

Comment: No. Think of an array being stored for a user as meta. This array is full of multiple keys who all have one sub array. I need to check of the array has been created yet for the user first. If not, I need to build the array with the key and value. If array exists, I need to use the key I know to find the correct array to add my value to.

Comment: can you post a demo array with example, as with the current example it is skeptical what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it further. If the array exits and already has a key/valueArray pair or pairs, then I need to find the key that I know and add new value to its sub array.

Comment: if you cannot explain it, how do you expect us to help you?

Comment: are there 2 arrays ?

Comment: I mean what else is there to explain? There's one array for a user. Inside that array, there are multiple key each of whom have their own sub array. So inside that user array could be a key "red" with a sub array containing "blue". If it exists and my key is "red", then I need to find it and the newest value, say "green"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dummy array to store your `$valOne` adn `$valTwo` and push this dummy array as the value for your key.

```
$dummy = array();
array_push($dummy, $valOne, $valTwo);
if (!empty($alpha)) {
    $alpha[$key] = $dummy;
} else {
    $alpha = array($key => $dummy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the associative array from the function get_data_array();

```
$alpha = get_data_array();
```

Assuming the below data you want to add into $alpha variable

```
$key = "red";
$valOne = "blue";
$valTwo = "green";
```

**Method 1**: If you know only few variables gonna to be added

```
$alpha[$key][] = $valOne;
$alpha[$key][] = $valTwo;
```

Reason, We know the variable names which is supposed to be added in the list which is based on different variable names. PHP will create the variable if it's not exists, so when we *$alpha[$key][]* it will create a memory for the key if it's not exits, if it's already exists then append to the array at last.

**Method 2**: If we are appending from another array

```
$valuesToAdd = array( $valueOne, $valTwo );
```

Here, $valueToAdd can have multiple values into the array. It can be coming from some outside source, or API, or user input like tags. In that case you can do the following code

```
foreach( $valuesToAdd as $element ){
    $alpha[$key][] = $element;
}
```

Here, we are looping every element from $valueToAdd and assigning to $element every time, so appending the value to the $alpha with the key.

Comment: I don't think any of these examples pertain to my example